# Syncing control sliders in LabVIEW with encoders through Arduino

Tags: arduino, serial-port, slider, labview

I'm controlling the voltage of an element in 2 ways:

1. A control slider in LabVIEW
2. A Rotary Encoder

I would like the control slider in LabVIEW to automatically update itself as I turn the rotary encoder. In a way, the slider would simultaneously act as a control and as an indicator.

I was able to read and display values over Serial in LabVIEW, but I need the control slider to move in realtime as I turn the rotary encoder.

Is there a way for the slider to act as both a 'control' and an 'indicator'? If not, how can I achieve synchronous behavior between the control slider and the rotary encoder?

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just right click on slider control->Create->Local Variable; 
Then put created local variable on the block diagram.

That's all, hope this helps.

[image]